# Proper notation of a nested square root - is there a notation akin to tetration which extends to roots

Tags: notation

In the way in which $x^{x^{x^{x}}}$ can be written as $x$ tetrated to 4 is there such a method to writing $\sqrt[...\sqrt{2}]{2}$ extending out to the left.

Comment: You mean like $\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}$?

Comment: No, like $2^{\frac1{2^{\frac1{2^{\frac1\dots}}}}}$

Comment: Yeah I intended it to be in the way in which karl stated